# Передача параметра из  PHP в скрипт Ubuntu

Tags: apache, php, ubuntu

пишу примерно так

```
<?php
 $run = "/var/www/script.sh {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}";
 exec($run);
 ?>
```

сам скрипт выглядит примерно так

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Hello word"
```

запускаю РНР на выполнение выдает:

```
PHP Notice: Undefined index:REMOTE_ADDR in /var/www/index.php on line 2.
```

Как быть?

Comment: вы через браузер этот index.php запускаете? Или с командной строки?

Comment: С командной строки.. .в браузере просто чистая страница.

Comment: $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] даже $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] не передается в заголовках через командную строку!!! только с браузера, т.к. апач или nginx эти заголовки отправляют скрипту, а простой php этого не делает.

Comment: $_SERVER -  Информация о сервере и среде исполнения в общем это переменная сервера и если не через него скрипт запущен ничего вам не выдастся.

Comment: т.е. я правильно понимаю, что данные будут поступать из РНР , только если он выполняется из браузера пользователя?

Comment: они будут поступать только в том случаи когда скрипт запущен через web сервер. В другом случаи вам надо самостоятельно переопределить переменную $_SERVER

Comment: ок , спасибо, понял.

Comment: еще один вопросик, что обозначет ts?
    $run = "ts /usr/share/nginx/html/script.sh {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}";

Comment: http://dev.man-online.org/man1/ts/

Answer (score 1):

как явствует из комментариев, вы вызываете скрипт из командной строки.

и пытаетесь использовать при этом информацию из переменной `$_SERVER`.

но эта переменная создаётся интерпретатором *php* **только** в случае его вызова *http-сервером* (насколько я знаю, только *apache-м*).

поэтому при запуске из командной строки эта переменная отсутствует, о чём вас и информирует интерпретатор.